# Accidentally deleted IIS server role

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis

We have two web servers : nevWeb nevDev. I needed to reinstall IIS on dev and removed it from web instead. This is where our entire intranet is. As of now everything is still accessable but it asked for a restart to finish the removal. I am afraid if it restarts everything is going to be gone.

Advice please

Comment: Define "everything" - a removal of IIS doesn't remove the web site files, just the IIS role.

Comment: So it does not delete inetpub? Also, the intranet will be offline

Comment: Isn't it offline already?

Comment: I think he has it "removed" but it wants to reboot to actually finish the installer housekeeping.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2GJMl.png

Comment: Only way to be sure things won't disappear is doing a backup. If all else fails you could just copy the backup to the working server, restart the other one, and create a re-direct rule temporarily while you get the other server back up.

Comment: This isn't a very large scale operation so it isn't like we will be losing $ with downtime. It is just kind of scary. I mean as long as I have a backup we should be fine./

Answer (score 2):

A) Do you have good backups in place?

B) Removing IIS Shouldn't have deleted your websites, just the IIS role, so you should be able to restore it.

C) Be ready to restore from backups just in case.

D) I'd make copies of everything in the subfolders with your content, just in case.

Comment: So I should just be able to readd the role and throw all the files in the inetpub directory?

Comment: That's the theory...but make no guarantees. See parts A and C. And D.

Comment: What is the worst case scenario?

Comment: You lose the website and rebuild from scratch.

Comment: If you have backups, you have a PITA getting restored data back in place after restoring the role.

Comment: If you have true backups, you spend an hour or two running a restore on the server and everything is back to the last backup point.

Comment: I have all the website files. So would the worst case I have to remake the IIS server role and make configuration is the same?

Comment: Best case, you reboot, the role is gone, you re-run the installer for the role to re-add IIS and the data was never deleted so you're back up and running.

Comment: Pretty much...if you have all the files backed up, reboot, cross your fingers, hope you can go home after another quick restore of role and reboot.